# Swift Instantiate NSView from .xib file

Tags: swift

I have created an HeadView.xib file and it's class file HeadView.swift. In the xib file I have the class set to HeadView.

In my ViewController I am calling the following code:

```
var myHeadView: HeadView?

@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : NSButton?) {
    let myrect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 350)
    posView = POSView.init(frame:myrect)
}
```

The Compiler is complaining with the following errors:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name and
>
> '()' is not convertible to 'HeadView'

In my HeadView Class I was hoping to instantiate the xib file with the following code

```
class HeadView: NSView {

    init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame:frameRect)

        var viewArray: NSArray?

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeadView", owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &viewArray)

        return viewArray.ObjectAtIndex(0)
    }
}
```

In Swift what does init return? Is there a better way to instantiate the view from file?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you don't call `init` in Swift

```
posView = POSView.init(frame:myrect)
```

should be

```
posView = POSView(frame:myrect)
```

Comment: Thanks. In the init function how is the view instantiated?

Comment: @MichaelRivers what do you mean? you can read this for more info about init function in swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_266

Comment: this does not really answers the question